# Adding custom arrow head styles in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, arrow

Is there any way to get more arrow head (marker) styles in Inkscape?  I find the styles supplied with the software inadequate.  Or can I use some other tricks to implement the arrow head function?  For example I want an arrowhead to be like 2 tiny lines from the tip.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw an arrow in inkscape](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54517/how-to-draw-an-arrow-in-inkscape) and more info here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/116194/alpha-for-node-markers-in-inkscape?rq=1

Comment: Rob: dude, my question is clearly different.

Comment: @YanKingYinDude, There are four people whom disagree. Please consider editing your question to explain how it is different ***or*** make the difference clear; you can also wait for another person to agree.

Comment: @Rob he is clearly asking for ways to add additional arrow heads - not *how* to get arrowheads. This is not a duplicate.

Comment: Does he use "add" or "get" anywhere? Did I offer a suggestion to address the concerns?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To create custom 'arrow heads' (markers) on a per-document level, use the 'custom markers' functionality:

https://inkscape-manuals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom-markers.html

You could then:

- save these in a default template, so they will be available to you in every new document (you can delete the actual objects, as long as you don't do 'Clean up document')
- save them in a separate document that you can copy them from when you need them
- save them as a 'markers.svg' file (note that this requires some manual editing of the SVG code): http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Customize-Files.html#Customize-Files-Markers - that way, they will always be available (until you update Inkscape, then the file is overwritten - make a backup!)